# IntelliJ's embedded terminal does not properly load my fish shell config

Tags: intellij-idea, fish

My Fish configuration in IntelliJ does not properly load and I see warnings about the path not being properly set.

`set: Warning: $PATH entry ...
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH ...`

So, IntelliJ does seem to be able to pick up my Fish config file which is located in ~/.config/fish/config.fish`.

Answer (score 12):

You have to disable the "shell integration" in IntelliJ. You can do that by going to the IntelliJ Settings and then "Tools > Terminal" and then deselecting the "Shell integration" checkbox.

Now my Fish config loads just fine :-).

Comment: I had a slightly different problem with fish within pycharm, but this solved it!